# Include file and nothing else in PHP?

Tags: php

I am currently including a new php file to an already existing page in the form of

```
if (...) {
   ... 
}

include("old_file");
```

Is there a way to  include this new file in the conditional without changing the part outside / including an else? 
e.g.

```
if (...) {
   Code that should be executed if condition is set. 
   include("new_file"); 

}
   Code that should not be executed if condition is set.
   include("old_file"); 
   ...
```

Comment: You can set a variable in `$new_file`, and check if its set in `old_file`, if it is, just don't parse any data there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `exit` to stop execution, or call `return` inside an included file (probably works fine outside an include as well).

```
if (...) {
   Code that should be executed if condition is set. 
   include("new_file"); 

   exit(); // terminates execution
}

// Code that should not be executed if condition is set.
include("old_file"); 
...
```

Comment: What about the content after `old_file`, judging by the `...` there, there are some content there, and OP only wants to skip the include if `new_file` was included.

Comment: No this was the answer, I did not know about return and quit!

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (...) {
   // Code that should be executed if condition is set. 
   include("new_file"); 
   return; // <-- now you skip the rest of the file. Actually, everything after the if block.
}
```